# Location values showing negative values

Tags: animation, 3d-view

Can anyone explain why after moving my characters foot upward on the Z axis, the values are showing as negative in viewport top right. Yet, in the Move window pop up bottom left they are positive value?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure without having the same rig, but in the top menu bar the _Transform Orientation_ is set to _Local_, while for the _Pose Mode_ it's set to _Global_. I could imagine it has something to do with that.

Comment: Thx Gordon, yes it absolutely did. My comment below on Gordon's post explained my issue in further detail.

Answer (score 3):

While move operation performs in world space, bone locations is shown in local space. So it is predictable because leg is pointed down.

Comment: Excellent thx. Knowing this is predictable makes all the difference.

Answer (score 2):

On the bottom left you'll see how many units you've moved your bone in the *Global* space (but you can swicth to *Local*), whereas in the N panel you'll see how many units you've moved your bone in its local space, i.e. compared to its default rest orientation and location

Comment: Great. Since I've posted this I've realized part of what has confused me in case anyone else runs into this issue, which was: I've been taking a class who's rig is set up differently than mine. The issue with mine is that the main control bone rotation in local space is different than that of the classes rig. For example, my hips in local space is set to the Y axis pointing up. Whereas the class rig is Z pointing up. This made the graph editor learning so confusing. Since then I've changed my rigs bone rotation to match the class rig. All makes sense now. Thx all!